# Are there more events in OpenLayers 3, besides "moveend"?

Tags: events, openlayers, pan, zoom

I am building an API on top of OpenLayers 3. I can't display here the whole code for professional reasons. This is a bit how my classes look like.

```
// external file xgis.js

xgis = {};


// xgis.map
xgis.map = function(options) {
    // map definitions ...
};
// Inherits from ol.Map
goog.inherits(xgis.map, ol.Map);
```

The goal is to build an SDK, which I named here "xgis". We want to implement some callbacks. For example, when I perform a zoomIn, I have a callback named onZoomIn that executes some code. I know that it is done with the event "moveend", like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joaorodr84/qaDZ8/).

Now, I want to implement some callback functions:

- onZoomIn --> fires after a zoom in
- onZoomOut --> fires after a zoom out
- onMapReady --> fires when the map is ready (has loaded all the layers)
- onPanEnd --> fires when the drag/pan has ended

Are there other events in OpenLayers 3, like "zoomend" or something?

Thanks

Comment: The olx http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/olx.interaction.html drag and rotote example http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/full-screen-drag-rotate-and-zoom.html